# multi Auto Complete

Tags: c#, winforms

I have connected a textbox to a autocompltecustomsource , is there any way to show list again when we insert ';' to list , something gmail do for 'To' textbox when you want to compose email .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the standard .net windows textbox. You have to manually implement this behavior by hooking to textchange/keypress event and parsing the text. It might be tricky little bit but not very complex to implement.